# Team Foundation Server - Files don't show in Source Control Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am currently doing a school project with two other members. We're using Team Foundation Server with Visual Studio to share the project and for collaboration.

I've added the project to Source Control (File > Add to Source Control > Choosing Team Foundation Version Control > Choosing Team Project Location) and checked in all changes.

Funny thing is, while my groupmates are able to connect to the server and configure workspace mappings, Source Control Explorer is empty for them. Mine, however, shows the appropriate files and folders (see image below)

[Source Control Explorer on my side. On my groupmates' machines, Source Control Explorer is empty. All it shows is "beitrik.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection" under the "Folders" section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db0RU.png)

Is there any way I could solve this? Right-clicking "beitrik.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection" and selecting Get Latest Version does not work either, since the resulting message will be that "All files are up to date".

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add them as Team members for your project? It sounds like their permissions are insufficient to view source code.

Comment: Hmm come to think of it, when I added them to the project, I got a notification regarding them having limited functionality as stakeholders... Could this be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your other contributors at the Stakeholder access level. Stakeholders cannot contribute code; it's a level of permissions intended for people who will be contributing requirements and monitoring project progress, but not actively contributing code. Stakeholders do not require any licensing, which is the big draw.

However, you get up to 5 users (including yourself) for free, so you can add them to the Basic level so they can contribute code. You can do that by going to the "Users" tab from the root of your project (e.g. http://youraccount.visualstudio.com).

Comment: How do I add them to a more permissive level, or does it depend on the member himself?

Answer (score 3):

Just as Daniel Mann mentioned, the other two member are working as a [stakeholder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/work/connect/work-as-a-stakeholder) that cannot contribute to Code.

> As a stakeholder, you can:
>
> - View, add, and modify items on the backlog
> - View, create, and modify work items such as stories, features, and    bugs
> - View, create, and save queries
> - View team dashboards and portfolio backlogs
> - Create and receive alerts when changes are made to work items
> - Submit, view, and change your feedback responses.

You can have 5 free users with [Basic Access](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs) which can contribute to Code. Configure it via following steps:

1. Open your VSTS account from Web Portal.
2. Select "Users" panel.

You can add or edit the users on this tab, change the access level to "Basic" will give the access to Code.

Refer to this link for more details: [Manage users and their access levels in your Visual Studio Team Services account](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/assign-licenses-to-users-vs)
[image]